# Is there a way to use dispatch_sync and dispatch_after

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

Is there an optimal way to use a mix of dispatch_sync and dispatch_after?

I have to loop through a list of Views, and wait for the data to load. Then scroll further and wait for data to load. and so on.

I do not want to execute the rest of the lines of code unless, this dispatch_sync is complete.

Code for reference:
Assumption:

1. "aFinalListToRender" is a list of views that I have filtered that I want to render in my context.
2. I have image size for the context figured out already.

   ```
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ? UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0):UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

           CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
           // Render the layer for the image.

           for (UIView *view in aFinalListToRender) {
               if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                   UIScrollView *aView = (UIScrollView *)view;
                   for (int i = 0; i < ceil(aView.contentSize.height/aView.frame.size.height); i++) {
                       for (int j = 0; j <= ceil(aView.contentSize.width/aView.frame.size.width); j++) {
                           // Scroll smartly for retina and non-retina devices
                           [aView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(aView.frame.size.width * j, aView.frame.size.height * i - (isRetina ? kRetinaValue: 0), aView.frame.size.width, aView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];

                           // TODO: Need to apply a synchronous-yet-asynchronous wait such that, 
                           // the current execution of the method pauses here, 
                           // yet allowing main thread to complete the execution, like rendering images etc,.
                           [aView.layer renderInContext:context];
                       }
                   }
               } else {
                   [view.layer renderInContext:context];
               }
           }

           aReturnVal = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```

Comment: Maybe you are taking a wrong approach to your problem. Can you explain in further details what exactly you are doing / trying to achieve? Maybe post some code?

Comment: I believe you can benefit from prioritizing async but I need to see more...

Comment: I have a list of views in an array, that may be scrollview / uiview / objects like those. I need to loop through each object, and render the view in the context. Pasting the code below.

Comment: @RKS: if you use a collection view or a table view, it will take care of incremental data loading for you. Is there a reason you can't use either of them?

Comment: Its not the data loading part I am worried about. I have the data with me. But when scrolling the scroll view, my images are not getting rendered properly. The views shows blank.

Comment: `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return `nil` unless inside of `drawRect:`.  You cannot use asynchronous coding in `drawRect:` (the context won't work any more after the method returns.)